# Which tools can be use to do user and service account auditing when using Cloud NAT on GCP?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-platform, audit, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-networking

We use our proxy server to access internet when we need to download packages from Internet like `conda`, `pip` and `debian` in 2 cases:
- from `AI Platform notebook`
- from `Dataflow` jobs (workers)

Our security team can monitor and see which user or services account is accessing which URLs (I think this is needed for audit and compliance. I don't know all the details but I think the idea is to be able to look back to so event and see what happened and what was done). The issue is that the proxy server is not design for such heavy load and it is a very bad practice to use it in this case. I want to use `Cloud NAT` which is specially design for that. Technically this is working perfectly.

Which tools from `GCP` or other provider is design to do such auditing and could be use to monitor what is done on the `Cloud NAT`? It doesn't see to be possible to get such information with Cloud NAT [Cloud NAT overview](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview), [Cloud NAT monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/monitoring) and [Cloud NAT log_fields](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/monitoring#log_fields). I am not an IT security person so maybe I am not using the right words and I hope experts will understand what I am looking for.

Comment: I discussed with the support team from GCP and I got the following information: 
"Cloud NAT is presently giving information on L3 and L4 layers (such as the source VM IP and port, source NAT IP and port, destination IP and port, and IP protocol of the connection). It would be interesting, for more complete monitoring purposes, to offer an information similar to HTTPS Proxy, such as L7-layer data, where, for example, the type of data and the URLs or the file names would be recorded."

Comment: A feature request was made and you can give your vote if you are also interested in such feature:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144886371

Comment: In your question, you state that your proxy can detect the user or service account for the network traffic. Unless your proxy is requiring authentication, that information i is not part of TCP traffic for commands like conda, pip, etc. Your security team can see the source and destination IP/Port but not the user identity of the application requesting the data. That information is not included in general TCP/IP traffic. Applications might include headers in higher layers (L7) such as `Authorization. Perhaps your security team means that they can record the URI for some requests.